# How to send string array list from adapter to its own activity

Tags: android

i am making application of attendance system and want to enter attendance. all students list is showing in listview and one by one element want to store in arraylist in listview adapter and send it to its own activity for storing arraylist in database

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried?

Comment: Use call back interface

Answer (score 1):

1:- by using interface

```
public interface ICallback { void onViewClick(ArrayList<String> mList); }
```

2:- by creating a public method on that activity which  takes an list as its argument.

```
public void onViewClick(ArrayList<String> mList){ // do your task here }
```

Answer (score 0):

**by using public method **

```
public void notifyMainAdapter(){

adapterName.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

**then call this method in adapter**

```
public void parentLIstUpdate(){
```

new MainActivity.notifyMainAdapter();
}